# saveSvgAsPng and modifyCSS or modifyStyle

Tags: image, d3.js, svg, png

I'm using this brilliant tool to save my d3.js svg as an image.

https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng

It works a treat but the only thing which is different is the font - It looks like I can specify a custom font using either `ModifyCSS` or `ModifyStyle` but I'm not sure how to do this.  I was hoping someone might have a working example?

Comment: I would try `modifyStyle` and modifying the `font-family`